# Using OBIEE Presentation Variables in Column Formula

Tags: variables, presentation, obiee

I have a dashboard prompt setting a presentation variable, based on months.

I am then trying to use the presentation variable in column formulae, however I am getting the following error when I try to preview it by selecting the month of February:

```
    State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError:   10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 27005] Unresolved column: "February". (HY000)
```

COlumn Formula :

```
      FILTER("Fact WayLeave Movements"."WayLeave Movement" USING ("Dim Date"."Month Name" IN (@{MonthName}{'January'})))
```

However when I use the same variable in the analysis filter (not in the column formula, but whole analysis) it seems to run fine. But I need the presentation variable applied on particular columns and not on all of them.

Could anyone please advise how to achieve this or what I am doing wrong when using the presentation variable in the column formula.v

Comment: we don't know what you are doing wrong when using the variable in the column formula, as you haven't told us how you are doing it. If you could edit your question to include the column formula that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

--Create a prompt with sql query which will fetch all month name or month number
--Assign a presentation variable to that prompt
--use that variable as a filter condition in analysis for that particular column.

So how it works is--when u select any month name from prompt that will be assigned to variable.And same month name in that variable will be used as filter condition for your column and and it will fetch data accordingly and report will run properly.
PFB a blog related to presentation Variable.

"https://blogs.oracle.com/ExalyticsOBIEE/entry/how_to_pass_presentation_variable

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have setup a presentation variable already called MonthName, yo will need to add the formulae like this `(@{MonthName}['@']{'January'})`. in between mothname and default January.

Hope that helps.